# How to skip/deal with empty cells in a Tailwind grid without changing the layout?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to create an input form of LABELS and INPUT elements that are vertically aligned in a row with some section headings.

See: https://play.tailwindcss.com/HAYm53a8UF

How can I get rid of the lines 16 and 20 without moving all other elements up? As soon as the _ is deleted, the layout changes. It seems empty cells are rendered differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- Line 16: `<div class="pt-5 h-12"></div>`
- Line 20: `<div class="pt-3 h-10">_</div>`

---

BTW, *they* are not 'cells in a Tailwind grid' and not rendered differently. The divs that contain your label and input are inside a `flex`. If you want to call them a 'grid cell', do not put them in a flexbox, but directly place them as a grid's children.

Comment: How did you come up with h-12 & h-10? I think you didn't use trial & error.

Comment: @RobertM.Münch I did use trial & error. That's because I didn't see any rules/pattern in the code.